# How to cancel a touch event in qt 4.6.3?

Tags: c++, qt

In [Qt-4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qevent.html#Type-enum) there isn't a `QEvent::TouchCancel` flag as in [Qt-5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html), how can I simulate a equivalent event in Qt-4?

**Background:**

I'm trying to implement kinetic scrolling in Qt-4, based on the approach described [here](http://blog.codeimproved.net/posts/kinetic-scrolling.html).

The basic framework remains the same, but I changed all `MouseEvent`s to `TouchEvent`s.

The problem is that, this code blocks `QEvent::TouchBegin` event on all child widgets and use it as the beginning of scrolling if the gesture is considered as a scroll, and posts a pair of simulated `QEvent::TouchBegin` and `QEvent::TouchEnd` when the gesture is considered as a tap.

For `QPushButton` needs `QEvent::TouchBegin` to trigger the animation effect of the "press". This approach, although makes the button still usable, eliminates such effect.

I'm trying to solve this problem by preserving the `QEvent::TouchBegin`, but cancel it when the gesture is considered as a scroll, and post a `QEvent::TouchEnd` when the gesture is considered a tap.

Question is, **how do I cancel touch event in QT-4?**

or, **how to construct a touch point at (0,0)?**

In my application, no widget at (0,0) accepts touch events, so posting a `QEvent::TouchEnd` at (0,0) effectively invalidates all started touch events. However, touch point in Qt doesn't have a usable constructor that can be used to generate an artificial touch point at arbitrary location, this workaround seems pretty difficult, too.

Finally, **last possibly solution**, how difficult is it to integrate `QScroller` class in Qt-5 to a Qt-4.6.3 project?

Answer (score 0):

There is version of the Qt5 QScroller code for Qt 4.8 here:
https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/kineticscroller

I used it successfully until I upgraded to 5. You should upgrade to 4.8 at least.